# I decided to test lightdm and suddenly got a lot of new software that I dont want in my dash...How to remove them?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, lightdm

I installed lightdm to take a look,but I didnt like it...so just removed.But now I have a lot of new stuff(apps) on my gnome dash that I dont want,like "clipter","users and groups","xarchiver",etc,etc...how can I remove all of that,please??

I'm in pop_os(ubuntu based)

Comment: Are you asking how to remove software in general or if there is a magical command to remove all the bloatware that came with a specific package?

Comment: A magical command would be great,lol...its just a lot of bloatware that I hated,but if I need to do one by one its ok...I guess the pop store is the way to go in that case...

Comment: `apt-get autoremove --purge`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these were all installed as dependencies of lightdm, `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` should get rid of them!

Source: [Ubuntu Manpage: apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: I would also recommend the Ubuntu Stack Exchange over this one for future questions like this, @JohnnySantos

Comment: Hey Kye,thanks but they already said to me that they don't allow it...only ubuntu,not derivatives